How to get the same ViewModel instance in Composable and Activity?
In my android project (jetpack compose) I have activity where in the onTagDiscovered method, I receive a message read from an NFC tag, which I want to pass to the currently active viewModel, where I will perform several operations (sending to the database, notifying the user, etc.).
The problem I have is to get the instance of currently active viewmodel in activity(and not create a new one).
If I do as below in code, I receive (shown in logs) two separate instances what is not suitable for further operations.
Logs:

composable ViewModel instance:  com.myapp.screens.registration_device.register_by_nfc.RegisterByNfcViewModel@7fb2d78
onTagDiscovered ViewModel instance:  com.myapp.screens.registration_device.register_by_nfc.RegisterByNfcViewModel@b7c078e

In my screen composable I use hilt to get viewmodel instance:
@Composable
fun RegisterByNfcScreen(navController: NavController, startOrEnd:String) {
    val registerByNfcViewModel:RegisterByNfcViewModel = hiltViewModel()

    Log.d("myLog","composable ViewModel instance:  $registerByNfcViewModel")
}


My viewmodel:
@HiltViewModel
class RegisterByNfcViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val iFirestoreManager: FirestoreManager,
    private val sharedPrefsManager: SharedPrefsManager
): ViewModel(){
}

Activity:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(),NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {
    private lateinit var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter
    private lateinit var userType:UserType
    
    private val registerByNfcViewModel: RegisterByNfcViewModel by viewModels()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        userType = SharedPrefsManager(this).getUserData().userType

        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                SetUpNavGraph(navController = navController)
            }
        }
            }
override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {
    Log.d("myLog","onTagDiscovered ViewModel instance:  $registerByNfcViewModel")
//some operation
registerByNfcViewModel.saveDataToDb(userName,company)

}
}

How to get in activity the some viewmodel instance as in composable function?

I finally managed to solve this problem myself using NavBackStackEntry. Viewmodel and Composable remain as before. I only changed activity as below. The Viewmodel instance taken from backstackentry is the some instance as in my Composable screen.
private lateinit var registerByNfcViewModel: RegisterByNfcViewModel

override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {
    val currentBackStackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntry
            currentBackStackEntry?.let { navBackStackEntry ->
                registerByNfcViewModel =
                     ViewModelProvider(navBackStackEntry)[RegisterByNfcViewModel::class.java]
            }

}


